# allow arabic letters when register new account

Tags: plugins, php, language

How can allow arabic letters when register new account ?

i don't need to lose any security.

If any of us, Arabs, want to register in any wordpress blogs we have to use English letters in “username” that will be very difficult for many of users.

Thanks.

Comment: What errors do you see? Can you give an username example?

Comment: @birige like this: محمد احمد

Comment: There's a long standing ticket [#5918](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5918) and a duplicate [#18666](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18666)  with a [plugin suggestion](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/18666/allow-arabic-usernames.php). But I'm not sure what side effects it would have.

Comment: Not working this questions is too old :(

Comment: Did you fix it Ahmed?